# Lync server user statuses are only being shown inside IE

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, office-integration

I have a community site, and under the members section their lync status will be shown as follow:-
[image]

But on Firefox, Chorme and Safari these statuses will not show? is there a way to force these statuses to be shown on these browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same behavior in 2010 as well in Firefox and Chrome and I believe it is still one of the few remaining ActiveX controls in SharePoint. Since Firefox and Chrome don't have ActiveX, there isn't a way to show them, unless your Chrome users run IE Tab.

> Users must have Office 2010, Office 2007, or Microsoft Office 2003
> with the latest service pack installed to view extended presence
> information on a SharePoint Server page.
>
> To display the presence
> indicator and its associated contact card (in Office 2010) or menu (in
> Office 2007 and Office 2003), SharePoint uses the Microsoft ActiveX
> control name.dll. The ActiveX control makes calls directly to the
> Microsoft Lync 2010 API, and then Lync makes MAPI or Exchange calls to
> supply the requested information.
>
> For details about how presence is
> displayed on a SharePoint Server page, see "How to add presence/pawn
> to SharePoint contacts list" on the Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN)
> at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=147181.

Answer (score 0):

Go through answer. This works in Firefox and IE both. but not work in Chrome. Reason also mentioned here.

[Presence indicator not working in Firefox but works in IE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157878/presence-indicator-not-working-in-firefox-but-works-in-ie/158502#158502)