# Presence indicator not working in Firefox but works in IE

Tags: chrome, presence-indication, firefox, ie, lync

Lync presence indicator works fine in IE but does not work in Firefox or Chrome.

After reading blogs I know that it calls `name.dll` through ActiveX which is possible in IE directly. I have searched for Firefox and found some link I have implemented, but no success.

I know this should work in Firefox as SharePoint default presence indicator works in Firefox.

Here is my code

```
if (IsSupportedNPApiBrowserOnWin()) {
    try {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            nameCtrl = new ActiveXObject("Name.NameCtrl");

        } else {
            nameCtrl = CreateNPApiOnWindowsPlugin("application/x-sharepoint-uc");
        }

        html += '<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href="#" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;" class="ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink" >' +
                    ' <span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10"><img onload="IMNRC(\'kaushal.khamar@xxxxx.com\')" name="imnmark"' +
                    ' title="' + currentDataItem.PreferredName + '" ShowOfflinePawn="1" class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-disconnected-8x72x32" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23" ' +
                    ' alt="' + currentDataItem.PreferredName + '" sip="kaushal.khamar@xxxxx.com" id="imn_' + currentDataItem.EmployeeNumber + ',type=sip" /></span></a></span></span>';

    }
    catch (ex) { }
}




function CreateNPApiOnWindowsPlugin(b) {
   var c = null;
   if (IsSupportedNPApiBrowserOnWin())
    try {
                     c = document.getElementById(b);
                     if (!Boolean(c) && IsNPAPIOnWinPluginInstalled(b)) {
                             var a = document.createElement("object");
                             a.id = b;
                             a.type = b;
                             a.width = "0";
                             a.height = "0";
                             a.style.setProperty("visibility", "hidden", "");
                             document.body.appendChild(a);
                             c = document.getElementById(b)
                        }
        } catch (d) {
    c = null
}
return c
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension/plugins which are used in Chrome and Firefox to support presence indicator are here which i discover after research and what i have conclude is.

**Chrome:** Use of **NPAPI** plugins are disabled in Chrome since 1 Sep 2015, please read more here. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en

**FireFox** intended to discontinue support for the **npspwrap.dll** and similar extensions in August or September 2015.

---

***EDIT:***

After some work and research now its works in **Firefox** and **IE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                nameCtrl = new ActiveXObject("Name.NameCtrl");

            } else {
                nameCtrl = CreateNPApiOnWindowsPlugin("application/x-sharepoint-uc");
            }
            attachLyncPresenceChangeEvent();
        }
    catch (ex) { }
});



    function IsSupportedNPApiBrowserOnWin() {
        return true; // SharePoint does this: IsSupportedChromeOnWin() || IsSupportedFirefoxOnWin()
    }

    function IsNPAPIOnWinPluginInstalled(a) {
        return Boolean(navigator.mimeTypes) && navigator.mimeTypes[a] && navigator.mimeTypes[a].enabledPlugin
    }

    function CreateNPApiOnWindowsPlugin(b) {
        var c = null;
        if (IsSupportedNPApiBrowserOnWin())
            try {
                c = document.getElementById(b);
                if (!Boolean(c) && IsNPAPIOnWinPluginInstalled(b)) {
                    var a = document.createElement("object");
                    a.id = b;
                    a.type = b;
                    a.width = "0";
                    a.height = "0";
                    a.style.setProperty("visibility", "hidden", "");
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    c = document.getElementById(b)
                }
            } catch (d) {
                c = null
            }
        return c
    }

    function showLyncPresencePopup(userName, target) {
        if (!nameCtrl) {
            return;
        }

        var eLeft = $(target).offset().left;
        var x = eLeft - $(window).scrollLeft();

        var eTop = $(target).offset().top;
        var y = eTop - $(window).scrollTop();

        nameCtrl.ShowOOUI(userName, 0, x, y);
    }

    function hideLyncPresencePopup() {
        if (!nameCtrl) {
            return;
        }
        nameCtrl.HideOOUI();
    }

    function getLyncPresenceString(status) {

        switch (status) {
            case 0:
                return 'available';
                break;
            case 1:
                return 'offline';
                break;
            case 2:
            case 4:
            case 16:
                return 'away';
                break;
            case 3:
            case 5:
                return 'inacall';
                break;
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
                return 'busy';
                break;
            case 9:
            case 15:
                return 'donotdisturb';
                break;
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }

    function attachLyncPresenceChangeEvent() {
        if (!nameCtrl) {
            return;
        }
        nameCtrl.OnStatusChange = onLyncPresenceStatusChange;
    }

    function onLyncPresenceStatusChange(userName, status, id) {
        var presenceClass = getLyncPresenceString(status);

        var userElementId = getId(userName);
        var userElement = $('#' + userElementId);
        removePresenceClasses(userElement);
        userElement.addClass(presenceClass);

    }

    function removePresenceClasses(jqueryObj) {
        jqueryObj.removeClass('available');
        jqueryObj.removeClass('offline');
        jqueryObj.removeClass('away');
        jqueryObj.removeClass('busy');
        jqueryObj.removeClass('donotdisturb');
        jqueryObj.removeClass('inacall');
    }

    function getId(userName) {
        return userName.replace('@', '_').replace('.', '_');
    }
```

And HTML is

```
html += '<div onmouseout="hideLyncPresencePopup()" onmouseover="showLyncPresencePopup(\'kaushal.khamar@xxxx.com\', this)" class="user" id="kaushal_khamar_xxxx.com">kaushal.khamar@xxxx.com</div>';
```

**This code works fine in Firefox and IE both.**

Answer (score 2):

Use of NPAPI plugins are disabled in Chrome since 1 Sep 2015, please read more here. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en

Not sure how to get it enabled, i thought a flag would be there to enable it back, but its not available. only PPAPI plugins can be enabled.

Similarly for Firefox as well, they have changed the way they support from 'always enabled' to 'click to enable', please read more here.
https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/02/28/update-on-plugin-activation/

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox Open menu -> Add-ons-> Plugins. In plugins select Microsoft Office (With description: The plugin allows you to have a better experience with Microsoft SharePoint) and set Always Activate

Comment: I have done this. but can't solve my problem.

Comment: Do Lync presence indicators work for users in standard peoplepicker fields in Firefox?

Comment: I have checked it in Firefox (version 41.0) with activated Microsoft Office 2013 plugin. Lync presence indicators for users work fine